# How to remove get_post_metadata using remove_filter inside a class?

Tags: filters, post-meta

This is the filter that i use.
`add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 10, 4);`

I have to use the `get_metadata` inside the above call back function. If I use directly it will create an infinite loop, so I believe I have to remove the filter temporally and enable it back .

But `remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);` does not seems to work

```
 public static function get_post_metadata($meta_value, $post_id, $meta_key, $single){
        if (is_admin()){
            return null;
        }

        remove_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0);
        $child_meta = get_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, false);
        $meta=null;
        if (WPKWP::get_parent()){
            $parent_meta = get_metadata('post', WPKWP::get_parent(), $meta_key, false);

            if (is_array($parent_meta) && is_array($child_meta)) {
                $meta = array_merge($parent_meta, $child_meta);
            } else {
                $meta = $parent_meta;
            }
        } else {
            $meta = $child_meta;
        }
        add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);
        return $meta;
    }
```

Update :
@kero add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4); which is added after removing seems to bring back the filter again. filter mode becomes active even if removed ..any fixes for that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hook a filter to catch get\_post\_meta when alternate a custom field output?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121679/how-to-hook-a-filter-to-catch-get-post-meta-when-alternate-a-custom-field-output)

Comment: Sorry, vote-close might have been a bit too quick. First of all: You have another question open - could you delete one of them or are they different? Then: Have you tried it, if the code works in a functional environment, is it really because you're using a class?

Comment: @kero oh.Not sure what's happening, my question is totally different from what's is shown. Also, my previous question is different and I have deleted that. It's inside the class otherwise I would have done it my self

Comment: @kero also I used the has_filter(), It returns true even after removing it ..so I believe that it does not work

Comment: Can you show your initial `add_filter()` call?

Comment: @kero yeah it's in the first line

Comment: Sorry. Try the priority of `10` in `remove_filter()`?

Comment: @kero ah thank you that went well :)

Comment: @kero it returns false but does not prevent get_metadata from breaking the website, any ideas

Comment: @kero `add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4);` which is added after removing seems to bring back the filter again. filter mode becomes active even if removed ..any fixes for that ?

Comment: Can you add this updated information to the question? So everyone is on the same page and doesn't have to dig through comments. I'm not sure how much time today I have for helping here, maybe someone else can step in

Comment: @kero i managed to fix it. add_filter('get_post_metadata', array(WPKWP::CLASS_NAME, 'get_post_metadata'), 0, 4); has to be added after returning value.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Feel free to answer your own question with that information (you have to wait a few days until you can accept it - but please do!), so future visitors can benefit from this as well

Comment: @kero couldn't have done without you! thanks for being here :)